# Virtual Background doesn't work in Zoom Chrome extension

Tags: chromebook, zoom-meeting

I was just wondering why my virtual background doesn't work on the Zoom Chrome extension. Also my settings look very different from what is shown online.

[image: Screenshot of settings page]

Answer (score 1):

Virtual backgrounds aren't supported on ChromeOS.  Even if they were, they probably wouldn't work well because they require a powerful processor which most Chromebooks don't have.

Pretty sure your Zoom Scheduler extension settings look different because of a recent update.  Mine used to look like the picture you linked to but now have a new look and more options.